# How to post links to facebook page from a website and make it public

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am trying to post links to my facebook page from a website using facebook client and graph api, the link is posted successfully, but it's only me that can see the posted link, i have set visibility property on facebook to public, yet other user can't see the posted link, This is my code:

```
private void PostToPage(string postLink)
    {
        dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
        messagePost.link = postLink;
        string acccessToken = "Removed";
        FacebookClient appp = new FacebookClient(acccessToken);
        try
        {
            var postId = appp.Post("Removed" + "/feed", messagePost);
        }
        catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
        {
            ViewBag.DisplayMessage = "Info";
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message + "failed to post link to facebook page.");
        }
        catch (WebExceptionWrapper ex)
        {
            ViewBag.DisplayMessage = "Info";
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message + "failed to post link to facebook page.");
        }
    }
```

any useful info on how to make it show to everyone will be appreciated